# While loop won't stop despite fulflling condition

Tags: c

I want to insert a condition into my program using a while loop. At the end it will ask you if you want to repeat the program from the beginning. If you type in 'n' then the program stops, if you type in anything else you continue. The problem is even when you write in 'n' it still does continue. I'm giving the code so you can see it for yourself:

I'm not giving the rest of the program since it works fine, it's just the loop itself that's the problem. When I made a condition involving an integer it works fine, it's just when I want a char string there's a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{

  char cnd[1];

  while(cnd != 'n') {
    printf("Would you like to continue? If not, then type in 'n', if you do then type in anything else: ");
    scanf("%1s", &cnd);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: cnd's real type is char*, in 'while' you compare char* and char. Your compiler should have warned you about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is safer without the need to define `cnd` as array like `cnd[1]` :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char cnd;

while(cnd != 'n') {
    printf("Would you like to continue? If not, then type in 'n', if you do then type in anything else: ");
    scanf("%1s", &cnd);
}

return 0;
}
```

When running your code, the following error would encounter which is self-explanatory.

```
[Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

which  refers to the error in `while(cnd != 'n')`

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the problem. But I actually tried to avoid using char without a string because it caused other problems with the program in general. I elaborated in the answer above.

Comment: Nice answer of yours (+1)

Comment: As noted in a comment on the question itself, `scanf()` with a "%1s" format specifier will write 2 characters at the address specified, since it must write a terminating NUL character. Use "%c" as in Andra's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using char array?? You can just use a regular char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char cnd;
    while(cnd != 'n') {
        printf("Would you like to continue? If not, then type in 'n', if you do then type in anything else: ");
        scanf("%c", &cnd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the problem. But I actually tried to avoid using char without a string because it caused other problems with the program in general. I elaborated in the answer above.